# calculate stft(Short-time Fourier transform) in tensor flow audio recognition

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, type-conversion, fft

I have a hard time running this piece of [example code](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/signal/mfccs_from_log_mel_spectrograms) here to convert the audio signal into stfts. I am using [label_wave.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/label_wav.py) and editing the 
"run graph" function.

```
def run_graph(wav_data, labels, input_layer_name, output_layer_name,
              num_top_predictions):
  """Runs the audio data through the graph and prints predictions."""
  data = np.fromstring(wav_data, dtype='int16')[-16000:]
  # Normalize the data
  data = data * 1.0 / (1 << 15)   # Range [-1 1]
  data = tf.reshape(data, (1, 16000))
  # tf.cast(data, tf.float32)
  stfts = tf.contrib.signal.stft(data, frame_length=1024, frame_step=256,fft_length=1024)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mfcc_label_wav.py", line 149, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "mfcc_label_wav.py", line 121, in main
    FLAGS.output_name, FLAGS.how_many_labels)
  File "mfcc_label_wav.py", line 115, in label_wav
    run_graph(wav_data, labels_list, input_name, output_name, how_many_labels)
  File "mfcc_label_wav.py", line 71, in run_graph
    fft_length=1024)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/signal/python/ops/spectral_ops.py", line 91, in stft
    return spectral_ops.rfft(framed_signals, [fft_length])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/spectral_ops.py", line 130, in _rfft
    input_tensor = _ops.convert_to_tensor(input_tensor, _dtypes.float32)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 950, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 883, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype float64: 'Tensor("stft/mul:0", shape=(1, 59, 1024), dtype=float64)'
```

Comment: the last line of error says it all ... you have a mismatch between float32 and float64 ... if you are on 64 bit hardware use float64 else float32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing tf.cast(data, tf.float32) isn't working. So i converted numpy array from float64 to float32 first and then reshaped the data.

```
  data = np.fromstring(wav_data, dtype='int16')[-16000:]
  # Normalize the data
  data = data * 1.0 / (1 << 15)   # Range [-1 1]
  data = np.float32(data)
  data = tf.reshape(data, (1, 16000))
  # tf.cast(data, tf.float32)
  stfts = tf.contrib.signal.stft(data, frame_length=1024, 
                                 frame_step=256,fft_length=1024)
```